# Rails 4 Error: Extract Param from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, controller

I struggle with getting the id param out of this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=13
```

Currently I am using this line of code to get it:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

This line directs to that:

```
redirect_to "/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=#{@job.id}"
```

Any help on how to achieve what I am trying to do is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have set param as job_id not id

Change this

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

To this

```
@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
```

Comment: Tested that already, getting this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubscriberjobsController#update
Couldn't find Job with 'id'=`

Comment: If I change everything to `id` instead of `job_id` I don't receive any errors but it extracts the wrong (or none) id. So my general approach on `Job.find(params[:id])` has to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

If the query param is `job_id`, then you need to use `params[:job_id]`, like MilesStanfield said, but are you sure that you want to use the `new` route with an id? If you are trying to edit an existing subscriber job, then the path should probably be `http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/13/edit`, and in SubscriberJobsController#edit, you would then use `params[:id]`. If you need to redirect to the edit form for the job, you can also use the path helper `redirect_to edit_subscriberjobs_path(@job)`. More info on routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem is that there is no SubscriberJob Model. It's just a controller to set the Job active and integrate stripe for payments.